# Unfiltering google sheet before querying data back into excel?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: I was thinking something like `.AutoFilter.ShowAllData`

I have a sub to query data from a linked google sheet and bring it into excel. I tried searching this, but couldn't find any info on how to toggle on/off a filter in google sheet before querying the data.

This is a shared google sheet, so some people forget to unfilter the data before I utilize this code. Any way to tack on an `.unfilter sheet` action or something when excel is connecting to the table in google?

```
Sub QueryGoogleSheets()
      Dim qt As QueryTable
      Dim url As String, key As String, gid As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    lrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 
    ws.Range("A5:Q" & lrow).ClearContents
      key = "key"
      gid = ""
      url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&key=" & key _
      & "&gid=" & gid
 
      Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, Destination:=ws.Range("A5"))
 
      With qt
          'unfilter google sheet 
          .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
          .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
          .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: I usually keep away from Google sheets - they're shared documents and desktop Excel sheets act significantly different.

Comment: @Jan I wish I could avoid it, but we need it to house a report that is updated by multiple people.

Comment: This may be helpful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/918585/office-scripts-clear-all-filters-(either-slicer-or